# enlarging div from center

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div with a background image which enlarges/shrinks. It is in a navigation which changes height based on scrolling.  I am using css transitions which is working well, however with line-heights, padding, etc changing I want it to scale from the center of the image.

CSS

```
header {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 125px;
  background-color: rgba(250,250,250,1);
  width: 100%;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  padding: 0 25px;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.35s ease;
  -moz-transition: height 0.35s ease;
  -ms-transition: height 0.35s ease;
  -o-transition: height 0.35s ease;
  transition: height 0.35s ease;
}
.brand {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  background: url('img/logo.png') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: contain;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.35s ease, width 0.35s ease;
  -moz-transition: height 0.35s ease, width 0.35s ease;
  -ms-transition: height 0.35s ease, width 0.35s ease;
  -o-transition: height 0.35s ease, width 0.35s ease;
  transition: height 0.35s ease, width 0.35s ease;
}
```

CSS when navigation is smaller

```
header.shrink {
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
}

header.shrink .brand {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

Comment: to scale from the center of element, use `transform: scale(0.5,0.5)`

Comment: Didn't think html is needed (wouldn't show anything to help question)

Comment: I want to animate the effect can I animate the transform?

Answer (score 0):

## [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/domslee/5dthvrL2/5/)

### Explanation

CSS margins and transitions can be used to achieve an animated shrink from the center (x-direction in respect to the previous size and the y-direction in respect to the parent element, the header). The solution posted here uses **known values** for **widths, heights and margins** to ensure that the image remains centered when  toggling between large and small.

The animation appears to be from the center because the margin, width and height is being **animated simultaneously** at the **same rate**.
[image: Image Demonstration]

CSS:

```
header, .brand {
    /* Animate for 0.35s */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.35s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.35s ease;
    transition: all 0.35s ease;
}

/* Enlarged styles */
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 125px;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: black;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    padding: 0 25px;
}
.brand {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    background: url('http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120104232844/steamplane/images/b/b0/Happy_Face_100x100.gif') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
}

/* Small styles */
header.shrink {
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
}
header.shrink .brand {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    
    /* Margin shorthand translates to:
     * - Top, bottom margins: 20px each
     * - Left, right margins: 30px each
     */
    margin: 20px 30px;
}

/* Button */
#button{
    margin-top: 130px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: the code I have works fine, it just scales from the top left corner, I want it to scale from the center of the div

Comment: Are you saying that you want the image scale from the center? Maybe [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Domination/5dthvrL2/2/) then?

Comment: exactly, which part is making it scale from the center?

Comment: This entire answer is a mess of external links spread between the answer and the comments that people like me who jsfiddle won't work for can't benefit from. Please include all of the answer in the post itself in a structured manner, and use snippets if you need to show example code.